# Design issue with encryption on my website

Tags: java, javascript, rest, encryption

I am building my website in which I am facing problems with implementing encryption. I am developing it using RESTful web services in java.

I found GibberishAES API for encryption from javascript. The encrypted message now goes to web service, but I have no clue how to decrypt it in the (java) web service. I know GibberishAES is not available in java, but is there any roundabout way?

Or, are there any encryption APIs which are supported for both Java and Javascript?

I also have the issue with (symmetric) key distribution for the website. It will have 100's of client (machines, in public network) and I don't know how to communicate the unique key for a particular machine to it.

Please help me with pointers in this regard.

Comment: Is there a particular reason your not just using SSL?

Comment: GibberishAES is just an AES-compliant library so you can use any java library which can handle AES. Why you're "messing" with encryption at all?

Comment: @Perception I am not really sure but I think we need certificate for using SSL. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Andreas Is it? I don't understand what I am messing up. I know that I am going seriously bad somewhere, can you brief it?

Comment: @techEnthusiast - yes, you need a certificate for SSL to work. You can use a self-signed certificate for testing but I recommend a trusted one for your live (production) app.

Comment: I can't help you here as you didn't provide any code (and I'm a noob in java :D) Maybe [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/symmetric.shtml) helps a bit - but the better option would be SSL as mentioned by @Perception

Answer (score 0):

[GibberishAES](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Security-Systems/Gibberish-AES-66219.html) implements AES encryption. AES is a symmetric cipher, that means that both parties must know a shared key. The problem of distributing the key is not trivial, and there exist well-known algorithms for doing so.

As it was mentioned in some comments, SSL already solves that problem, because it negotiates the generation of a distributed secret key, that is later used for encryption. If for any reason you cannot use SSL, you should adopt some mechanism for secure generation or transport of the secret key. For instance, you could generate a ephimeral RSA key pair in the client, send the public key to the server, and have the server return the secret (AES) key in wrapped form.